# Repair the alignment of the first column

Tags: alignment

I have rearranged a table so that all numbers are aligned at the decimal point. This has also worked so far.
However, the first column has become very unsightly:

[image]

I want to left-align the first column and align the rest of the table to the decimal point.

The first column of my table should look like this:

[image]

I think the error lies here in this command:

`\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{$}r<{$}@{}>{$}l<{$} | S | *{4}{S} @{}}`

How can I specify this command so that my desired table comes out?
Many thanks in advance!

Hier is the code of my table:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{floatrow} \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top} \floatsetup[table]{capposition=top} \usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{d}{S[table-format=2.1]}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \mcc{mO{C}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}

\begin{table}[!h]  
\caption{\label{tab:table_13}CAAR (-2;+2) of target firms according to transaction forms and deal characteristics} 
\sisetup{table-format=2.1,
             table-space-text-post={***}
             }
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{$}r<{$}@{}>{$}l<{$} | S | *{4}{S} @{}}
\Xhline{1.2pt} 
\mcc{2}[c|]{\makecell[t]{Description}} & \mcc{1}[c|]{\makecell[t]{All\\transaction\\forms}} & \mcc{1}{\makecell[t]{Acquisition Of\\ Partial Interest}} & \mcc{1}{\makecell[t]{Acquisition Of\\ Majority Assets}} & \mcc{1}{\makecell[t]{Acquisition Of \\ Remaining Interest}} & \mcc{1}{\makecell[t]{Merger}}\\
\Xhline{0.8pt}
\addlinespace[0.3em]  
\hspace{0em}{\textbf{Deal Attitude}}&\\ 
\hspace{1em} Friendly & 13.1 * * * & 5.7 * * * & 11.2 * * * & 13.4 * * * & 20.3 * * *\\ 
\hspace{1em} Hostile & 15.7 * * * & 5.1 & 24.8 & 12.4 & 17.1 * * *\\ 
\hspace{1em}Neutral & 5.0 * * * & 4.7 * * * & 5.1 & 17.6 & 7.6\\ 
\hspace{1em}No Applicable & -1.5 & -1.0 & -8.3 & NA & 0.5\\ 
\hspace{1em}Unsolicited & 16.3 * * * & 12.0 * & 12.7 * * & 82.4 & 16.4 * * *\\  
\hspace{0em}{\textbf{Location}}&\\ 
\hspace{1em}cross-border & 13.9 * * * & 6.7 * * * & 22.9 * * * & 14.8 * * * & 21.9 * * *\\ 
\hspace{1em}domestic & 11.7 * * * & 4.6 * * * & 10.1 * * * & 13.1 * * * & 18.5 * * *\\  
\hspace{0em}{\textbf{Industry}}&\\ 
\hspace{1em}cross industry & 11.9 * * * & 4.8 * * * & 10.7 * * * & 15.7 * * * & 19.9 * * *\\ 
\hspace{1em}same industry & 14.4 * * * & 8.5 * * * & 12.5 * * * & 9.7 * * * & 19.7 * * *\\  \hspace{0em}{\textbf{Financial}}&\\ 
\hspace{1em}Financial & 10.0 * * * & 3.3 * & 5.1 & 15.2 * * * & 16.1 * * *\\ 
\hspace{1em}Non-Financial & 12.8 * * * & 5.7 * * * & 11.7 * * * & 13.5 * * * & 20.3 * * *\\
\Xhline{1.2pt}
\end{tabularx} \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: not directly related but never use `tabularx` if you are not using `X` columns, it can do noithing useful in that case, Just use `tabular` here.

Comment: you want left aligned text inthe first column, but you have specified right aligned math mode? `>{$}r<{$}`  shouldn't that be simply `l` ?

Comment: What should this command look like then? Suggestions?

Comment: replace `>$r<$` by `l` (what was the intention of math mode there? and replace `{tabularx}{\textwidth}` by `{tabular}`

Comment: Someone else suggested this command to me on a similar table. I simply applied it to my current example. Your sugguestion still doesn't really work that way.
The table content is arranged correctly, but not the headings.
Did you run the code and does it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier if you use `tabular*` instead of `tabularx`.

No `\multirow` is necessary and no “gaped cells”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]

% local command for split cells
\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}

\sisetup{
  table-format=-1.2,
  table-space-text-post={***}
}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % let TeX do the work

\caption{\label{tab:table_13}CAAR (-2;+2) of target firms according to
  transaction forms and deal characteristics} 

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{
  @{\quad}
  l
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=-1.1]
  S[table-format=-1.1]
  S[table-format=-1.1]
  S[table-format=2.1]
  S[table-format=2.1]
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\quad Description} &
{\smash{\splitcell{All\\transaction\\forms}}} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Acquisition of} &
{Merger}
\\
\cmidrule{3-5}
&&
\splitcell{Partial \\ Interest} &
\splitcell{Majority \\ Assets} &
\splitcell{Remaining \\ Interest} &
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\textbf{Deal Attitude}} \\
  Friendly       & 13.1 *** &  5.7 *** & 11.2 *** & 13.4 *** & 20.3 *** \\
  Hostile        & 15.7 *** &  5.1     & 24.8     & 12.4     & 17.1 *** \\
  Neutral        &  5.0 *** &  4.7 *** &  5.1     & 17.6     &  7.6     \\
  No Applicable  & -1.5     & -1.0     & -8.3     & {NA}     &  0.5     \\
  Unsolicited    & 16.3 *** & 12.0 *   & 12.7 **  & 82.4     & 16.4 *** \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\textbf{Location}} \\
  cross-border   & 13.9 *** &  6.7 *** & 22.9 *** & 14.8 *** & 21.9 *** \\
  domestic       & 11.7 *** &  4.6 *** & 10.1 *** & 13.1 *** & 18.5 *** \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\textbf{Industry}} \\
  cross industry & 11.9 *** &  4.8 *** & 10.7 *** & 15.7 *** & 19.9 *** \\
  same industry  & 14.4 *** &  8.5 *** & 12.5 *** &  9.7 *** & 19.7 *** \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\textbf{Financial}} \\
  Financial      & 10.0 *** &  3.3 *   &  5.1     & 15.2 *** & 16.1 *** \\
  Non-Financial  & 12.8 *** &  5.7 *** & 11.7 *** & 13.5 *** & 20.3 *** \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The input is also easier: the part titles are typeset with a `\multicolumn` that ignores the 1em padding. With `\smash` the split cell will have zero depth.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadalign{tc}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}

\newcommand{\rowhead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\bfseries #1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{\label{tab:table_13}CAAR (-2;+2) of target firms according to transaction forms and deal characteristics} 
\sisetup{table-format=-2.1,
             table-space-text-post={***}
             }
    \begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{1em}}l  *{5}{S} @{}}
\toprule
\multirow{3.5}{*}{\thead{Description}} 
& {\multirow{3.5}{*}{\thead{All\\transaction\\forms}}} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Acquisition Of}
& {\multirow{3.5}{*}{\thead{Merger}}}\\
\cmidrule{3-5}
&&{\thead{Partial\\ Interest}} 
& {\thead{Majority\\ Assets}} 
& {\thead{Remaining\\ Interest}} 
\\
\midrule 
\rowhead{Deal Attitude}\\ 
Friendly       & 13.1 * * * & 5.7 * * * & 11.2 * * * & 13.4 * * * & 20.3 * * * \\ 
Hostile        & 15.7 * * * & 5.1       & 24.8       & 12.4       & 17.1 * * * \\ 
Neutral        & 5.0 * * *  & 4.7 * * * & 5.1        & 17.6       & 7.6        \\ 
No Applicable  & -1.5       & -1.0      & -8.3       & NA         & 0.5        \\ 
Unsolicited    & 16.3 * * * & 12.0 *    & 12.7 * *   & 82.4       & 16.4 * * * \\  
\addlinespace
\rowhead{Location}\\ 
cross-border   & 13.9 * * * & 6.7 * * * & 22.9 * * * & 14.8 * * * & 21.9 * * * \\ 
domestic       & 11.7 * * * & 4.6 * * * & 10.1 * * * & 13.1 * * * & 18.5 * * * \\ 
\addlinespace 
\rowhead{Industry}\\ 
cross industry & 11.9 * * * & 4.8 * * * & 10.7 * * * & 15.7 * * * & 19.9 * * * \\ 
same industry  & 14.4 * * * & 8.5 * * * & 12.5 * * * & 9.7 * * *  & 19.7 * * * \\ 
\addlinespace 
\rowhead{Financial}\\ 
Financial      & 10.0 * * * & 3.3 *     & 5.1        & 15.2 * * * & 16.1 * * * \\ 
Non-Financial  & 12.8 * * * & 5.7 * * * & 11.7 * * * & 13.5 * * * & 20.3 * * * \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```